# Javascript Client-side pass value in server-side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, devexpress

I have a label that has a value from a client-side and I want to get that value to pass in server side. I tried to use Hidden Field but nothing happens. Can anyone help me with this? Thank you!

Here's what I have

**FrontEnd**

```
<asp:Label ID="LblProd" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" Visible="true" Value="Hidden" runat="server"/>

<dx:GridViewDataTextColumn FieldName="prod" Name="dd_prod" ShowInCustomizationForm="true" VisibleIndex="3">
    <SettingsHeaderFilter>
        <DateRangePickerSettings EditFormatString="" />
    </SettingsHeaderFilter>

    <EditItemTemplate>
        <dx:ASPxComboBox ID="ASPxComboBoxProduct" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" DataSourceID="prod" TextField="pname" ValueField="pcode">
            <ClientSideEvents SelectedIndexChanged="function(s, e) { OnProductChanged(s); }"></ClientSideEvents>
        </dx:ASPxComboBox>
    </EditItemTemplate>
    </dx:GridViewDataTextColumn>
```

**Here is My JavaScript code**

```
function OnProductChanged(s, e) {
          var selected_index = s.lastSuccessValue;
          var aa = document.getElementById('LblProd').innerText = selected_index;
      }
      onload = OnProductChanged;
```

That is my code to get the value of my dropdown and store it in Label(LblProd).

And below is my code to get the value of label and pass it in HiddenField to be able to sent it to server.

```
function getProduct() {
        var label = document.getElementById("<%=LblProd.ClientID %>");
        label.innerText = selected_index;
        document.getElementById("<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>").value = label.innerText;
    }
```

And below is my backend

```
If Me.IsPostBack Then
            LblProd.Text = Request.Form(HiddenField1.UniqueID)
        End If
```

Nothing happens I see then every postback the value is returning to nothing.

Comment: Use `HiddenField1.Value` in code behind instead of `HiddenField1.UniqueID`. The server control already contains the value by passing it in client-side, it is unnecessary to use `Request.Form` method here.

Comment: still not working.

Comment: Have you tried `document.getElementById("<%=LblProd.ClientID %>").innerText = selected_index;`? Seems that you need `ClientID` both for assigning and passing value on client-side.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto yes. Still not working. Can you provide me a working sample?

Comment: Have you checked  that your HiddenField1 value is filled with the label text and that your "document.getElementById("<%=HiddenField1.ClientID %>").value = label.innerText;" command is working properly?